# CSS Border, outside table border not showing

Tags: html, css

I've been using 'border = 1' in my HTML, which looks fine, but I realise it would be better to use CSS, so I created a basic border class, like so...

```
.basicborder table, .basicborder th, .basicborder td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The borders appear around the th and td's but not around the outside of the table itself. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: whats the structure of your html? does your table have the class `basicborder`? if so you need `table.basicborder` in your css and not `.basicborder table` or with your css the table's container must have the class `basicborder`

Comment: use the snippet editor to post your html strucure, plz

Comment: Yes, my table had the class 'basicborder' and that fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS looks fine to me, but you can better use:

`table.basicborder, th.basicborder, td.basicborder{border: 1px solid black;}`

So, the selector starts with the least specific selector (the HTML element, instead of the class).

But it should already work fine, if you have linked your HTML properly. Do your table, th and td elements have a `class="basicborder"` attribute each?

edit:

If i comprehend correctly, this would be the best solution.

You make a basic style for all 's with just `table,td,th{ etc...`
Then you add to the ones with a different style a class, lets stay *differentborder*.Now you make a CSS saying the following: `table.differentborder, .differentborder td, .differentborder th{ your style }`
This selects your tables with the class, and all td's an th's where a parent has the class differentborder.

For more fun with CSS selectors you can look on the [W3Schools CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that I could even do it that way around. It works fine now with table.basicborder, .basicborder th, .basicborder td { border: 1px solid black;} but not if I also switch the th and td's around as you've done above. Only my table has the class, the td's and th's don't.

Comment: Yes, that explains something :). If you want to do it totally correct you should use `table.basicborder, th, td{border: 1px solid black;}`, because otherwise it tries to find th's and td's with the class basicborder. You can also add the class to all th's and td's and use the code in my original answer. You can also just bash the whole class and use `table, th, td{border: 1px solid black;}` so it will be applied to all tables, td's and th's.

Comment: The thing is, I have a couple of tables that I don't want to be affected by this, so table.basicborder, th, td.. etc, causes those to be affected too. Having said that, since those tables are the minority, it would probably be better to format all tables with table, th, td{ etc and then just separately format the other tables to remove their borders.